# Compress files .zip from php5

Tags: php, linux, console

I have a number of files from my database, extract the names with their routes and placed on simple arrays. 
Then I try to compress on .zip using linux console command with shell_exec works but not me.

Will exist another method to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function provided by the php5 ((PHP 5> = 5.2.0, PECL zip> = 1.1.0))

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = 'files.zip';

$files = array();
$files[] = "file1.txt";
$files[] = "file2.flv";


if($zip->open($filename,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) 
{
        for( $i=0; $i<count($files) ; $i++ )
          $zip->addFile($files[$i]);

        $zip->close();
        echo "ok $filename";
}
else 
        echo "failed ".$filename;
?>
```

For more information http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

Comment: How do I check if I have it installed on my php?